# Julia DataFrame - compare row value with previous row

Tags: dataframe, julia, row

Example of first rows of the DataFrame with original columns Height and Size:

[image: 1]

Desired results are in new additional columns Result_by_row and Result_by_column.
Result_by_row: compare 2 row value with 1 row value and if higher return True in new column Result_by_row (example: 46 > 17, return True in row 2 column Result_by_row).
Result_by_column: same principle but with different columns (example: 46 > 32, return True in row 2 column Result_by_column).

Thanks.

New with Julia, so don't know how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example way how you can do it:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(Height=[32.0, 35.0, 63.0, 84.0, 72.0], Size=[17.0, 46.0, 18.0, 56.0, 6.0])
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ Height   Size
     │ Float64  Float64
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │    32.0     17.0
   2 │    35.0     46.0
   3 │    63.0     18.0
   4 │    84.0     56.0
   5 │    72.0      6.0

julia> using ShiftedArrays: lag

julia> df.Result_by_row = df.Height .> lag(df.Height)
5-element Vector{Union{Missing, Bool}}:
      missing
  true
  true
  true
 false

julia> df.Result_by_column = df.Size .> lag(df.Height)
5-element Vector{Union{Missing, Bool}}:
      missing
  true
 false
 false
 false

julia> df
5×4 DataFrame
 Row │ Height   Size     Result_by_row  Result_by_column
     │ Float64  Float64  Bool?          Bool?
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │    32.0     17.0        missing           missing
   2 │    35.0     46.0           true              true
   3 │    63.0     18.0           true             false
   4 │    84.0     56.0           true             false
   5 │    72.0      6.0          false             false
```